# I am able to send a data from one jade page to other but I am not knowing how to use that in other page in app.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am sending the variable 'id' from index page to info/studs page, and it is doing that part,but I am not able to use that variable in app.js

```
extends layout
block content
    .container
        .col-md-4
            h2 Name
                a(href='../info/studs?id=#{user.id}') #{user.name}

    and app.js file containing

app.get('/info/studs',function(req, res){
    //Here I want to use variable 'id'
```

});

Comment: Post some code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into the [req.query](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query) object for more information.

To specifically answer the question:

```
app.get('/info/studs',function(req, res){
    //Here I want to use variable 'id'
    var id = req.query.id
    //You can now use the 'id' variable as you want.
})
```